# SQL to search and delete with several keycolumns

Tags: sql, sql-server

A bit bad title maybe but I try to explain what I mean.

I use SQL like this to build a list

```
SELECT id 
FROM parcel 
WHERE id IN (113715, 113824, 113855, 113954, 114010, 114116, 114272, 114329)
```

where `ID` is a column in parcel table that is quarantined to be unique, very straightforward.

But some tables use many columns to be unique.

```
SELECT id1, id2 
FROM trip 
WHERE id1, id2 IN ((113715, 113824), (113855, 113954), (114010, 114116),(114272, 114329))
```

The last SQL is obviously not working.

I want to select rows where

```
id1 = 113715 and id2=113824 or
id1 = 113855 and id2=113954 or
id1 = 114010 and id2=114116 or
id1 = 114272 and id2=114329
```

In reality the generated SQL can contain 500 - 1000 ids.

What SQL should I use ?

**EDIT**

This is a generated SQL. The ID's come from another database on another server so JOIN for example is not possible.

Comment: This could become slow. Where do the IDs come from? If from a table you can join that

Comment: as you said like this where id1 = 113715 and id2=113824 or id1 = 113855 and id2=113954 or ...

Comment: If possible I would like to use IN operator as I imagine that is faster

Comment: Put those values in a temoprary table and do a join.

Comment: Juergen, I add more info to question. JOIN is not possible

Comment: `WHERE (id1,id2) in ((113715,113824),(113855,113954), ...)` is valid in some DBMS (though I don't know whether this is standard SQL). It is not valid in SQL Server.

Comment: Nice. 4 answers in the same minute where all answers are basically the same. There has to be a hat or badge for this kind of thing :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT id1, id2 FROM trip 
INTERSECT
select id1, id2 from (values (113715,113824),(113855,113954),(114010,114116),(114272,114329)) a(id1,id2)
```

USE [`INTERSECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)

Comment: `INTERSECT` is a great idea for this query.

Comment: Note the `INTERSECT` is different than `INNER JOIN`, it returns distinct values

Comment: You can use `intersect all` to return all values

Answer (score 5):

You could use a join with a values list:

```
SELECT id1, id2 
FROM trip 
INNER JOIN (VALUES (113715,113824),(113855,113954),(114010,114116),(114272,114329)) V(a, b)
ON id1 = a 
AND id2 = b
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the generated ids like this?

```
;WITH GenerateIds AS
(
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
   -- Paste the Id list below
   (113715,113824),(113855,113954),(114010,114116),(114272,114329)
  ) t(id1, id2)
)
-- Use inner join
SELECT id1, id2 FROM trip INNER JOIN GenerateIds g ON 
   trip.id1 = g.id1 AND trip.id2 = g.id2
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately SQL Server doesn't support tuples in `IN` like

```
SELECT id1, id2 
FROM trip 
WHERE (id1,id2) in ((113715,113824),(113855,113954),(114010,114116),(114272,114329));
```

which is valid in some other DBMS.

So you can either follow your own suggestion

```
SELECT id1, id2
FROM trip 
WHERE (id1 = 113715 and id2 = 113824)
   OR (id1 = 113855 and id2 = 113954)
   OR (id1 = 114010 and id2 = 114116)
   ...;
```

Or use a temporary table, cte or the like. Easiest might be to join a values clause:

```
SELECT trip.id1, trip.id2
FROM trip 
JOIN (VALUES (113715,113824),(113855,113954),(114010,114116),(114272,114329))
  AS src(id1, id2) ON src.id1 = trip.id1 AND src.id2 = trip.id2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Simple Query:

```
SELECT id1, id2 
FROM trip 
WHERE 1 = 1
AND ((id1 = 113715 and id2=113824) 
    OR (id1 = 113855 and id2=113954) 
    OR (id1 = 114010 and id2=114116) OR (id1 = 114272 and id2=114329))
```